# Android - Why BackStackCount = 0 when it still navigates back and forth just fine?

Tags: android, navigation, xamarin, back-stack, fragmentmanager

Inside the OnBackPRessed Overriden method I try to see how many entries is there on the back stack. After Navigating from **Activity 1** forward to **Activity 2** and then forward to **Activity 3** - I get back 0 when I call FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount.

**Should not I have at least 2 entries in there?**
What totally confuses me is that I would go back to **Activity 2** and then to **Activity 1** just fine meaning there are some entries. Then why would it return 0 entries when I ask it for it???

Another thing is let's say I am in the **Activity 3** I add to back stack within the **Activity 3** and then I would get back EntryCountOfOne - I add the other one and I get back 2.

Does that mean that Fragment Manager is Sort of Per Activity?

I thought that the BackStack is Global and you should be able to see what is on it or at least get a proper count regardless of what Activity you are in.

Please sort me out my people - trying to understand the concept

```
int iBackStackEntryCounter;     
iBackStackEntryCounter = this.FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `FragmentManager's` back stack is another thing which I won't get into right now so as not to confuse you more.
The back stack holds all activities in groups of **tasks** something like: [image: Back stack with tasks]
The stack is a concept you should read about in depth in [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
and [Providing Proper Back Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve so I'll assume you want to "know" when your app is about to go to the background due to the back key being pressed until your last activity is about to be closed. In this case the best pattern would be to hold a counter of how many activites you have created (by incrementing the counter in each `onStart` and decrementing in each `onStop`) and overriding `onBackPressed` where you can do something like:

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
{
  if (counter = 1)
    //it means you are about to press back in your last activity so do what you must
  else
    base.OnBackPressed();//it's not your last activity so just act normal
}
```